# How do I sort my x-axis by ascending month order?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

So I have a dataframe with the indices as datetime objects. 
[image: Image1]
I have created a new column to indicate which month each 'ride' in the dataframe is in:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime    
months = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x:dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%b %Y')).tolist()
df['months'] = months
df1 = df[['distance','months']]
```

Which gives:

[image: image2]

When I try to plot it onto a line graph using seaborn using months as the x-axis, it sorts it in alphabetical order, starting with april then august, etc.

```
l = sns.lineplot(x='months',y='distance',data=df1)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image: image3]

I don't really understand why it does this as in the dataframe that I use, the months are sorted in ascending order according to their months. Is there a way I can make it so my x-axis starts with Jan2018 and ends in July2019?

Comment: have you tried `l = sns.lineplot(x='months',y='distance',data=df1, sort=True)`?

Comment: Yep I have, it doesn't work. It's strange because when I used `sns.countplot(x='months',data=df1)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)` with the exact same dataframe, it sorts it for me.

Comment: You've made your dates strings, and my guess is that seaborn is sorting them for you.  Instead, leave as dates, and set the locator to a month locator, and the formatter to a date formatter.  https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html should get you going in the correct direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The x-coordinates must be numeric. When you supply an array of strings, Seaborn automatically sort it alphabetically. What you want can be achieved with `sort=False` (the default is `True`):

```
# True or omitted
sns.lineplot(x='month', y='distance', data=df1, sort=True)
```

[image: Sort = True]

```
# Set to False to keep the original order in your DataFrame
sns.lineplot(x='month', y='distance', data=df1, sort=False)
```

[image: Sort = False]