# Why cant is my x values in sns.relplot messing up the values and not putting them in order?

Tags: python, pandas, date, plot, seaborn

```
data = pd.read_csv('personal expenses without rent.csv')

data.columns = ['month-year', 'Expenses (USD)', 'unnamed', 'unnamed', 'unnamed', 'unnamed']

data
```

month-year column looks like this: Feb-19, Mar-19, Apr-19, and so on, until Jul-20

```
sns.relplot(x = 'month-year', y = 'Expenses (USD)', data = data, kind = 'scatter')
```

But when i plot the points, it shows all data points but x axis values are not in the right order. why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort my x-axis by ascending month order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612862/how-do-i-sort-my-x-axis-by-ascending-month-order)

Comment: nope, when I use sns.relplot, there is not argument called 'sort'. And when I try to use sns.lineplot and do sort = False, then it gives me erorr saying "no numeric data type values to aggregate".